# Derivative with respect to initial condition for the solution of an SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, integration, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-approximation

Suppose we have an SDE (assuming the Lipschitz continuous conditions required for the existence of the solution):
\begin{align}
dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dW_t
\end{align}
and define its solution starting at $x$ at $t=0$ as follows :
\begin{align}
X_t^x = x + \int_0^t\mu(X_s,s)ds + \int_0^t\sigma(X_s,s)dW_s
\end{align}
or using Kunita's notation of stochastic flows
\begin{align}
\Phi_{0,t}(x) := X_t^x = x + \int_0^t\mu(X_s,s)ds + \int_0^t\sigma(X_s,s)dW_s
\end{align}
Kunita defines and shows the existence of the derivative $\frac{\partial \Phi_{0,t}}{\partial x}(x)$ in [his lecture notes](https://mathweb.tifr.res.in/sites/default/files/publications/ln/tifr78.pdf).
[image]

I was wondering if this derivative can be used in a Taylor expansion to approximate $\Phi_{0,t}(x_1)$ knowing $\Phi_{0,t}(x_0)$, for example :

\begin{align}
X_t^{x_1}(\omega) = X_t^{x_0}(\omega) + (x_1 - x_0)\times\frac{\partial \Phi_{0,t}}{\partial x}(x_1) + o(x)
\end{align}
It seems to work for the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck and Geometric Brownian processes, but I cant find a reference to this subject or any rigorous definition.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for. Kunita shows (almost sure) existence of a (continuous) path-wise derivative, so you can just apply Taylor's theorem for (almost all) fixed $\omega$. Do you want some type of uniformity/control in the approximation?

Comment: It is precisely what you mentioned: a Taylor's expansion for a fixed $\omega$. I couldn't find a reference to this matter (the Taylor expansion), but indeed - as you said - since the path-wise derivative exists and is continuous, we can directly apply Taylor's expansion to it, thanks